# Screen scraping an interactive web application

Tags: screen-scraping, web-crawler

I need to screen scrape certain information from an *interactive* web application; more to the point I have to screen scrape that information from a Form once the user of that web application has submitted (POSTed presumably) that form.

What options or choices do I have for that?

The solution has to be minimally invasive i.e. I can't rely on Fiddler; it also needs to have a small footprint (i.e. I cannot install too many 3rd-party apps or tools to accomplish this).

The data that will be screen scraped will be tied together with a C# application that runs in the background on the desktop system. And this is a Windows-based desktop system.

I am completely open to non-C# based solutions e.g. Ruby, Python, etc. as long as the constraints above are met.

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4294487/1333493

Answer (score 0):

For c# there is htmlagilitypack, but if it were me I would use ruby mechanize or watir/selenium

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly on your requirements, but since you know Ruby, I believe using Mechanize will be enough. It's a very powerful web automation library and easy to set up as well.

You can check this article on how to set it up on Windows:

http://webmites.org/ruby-mechanize-web-scraping-made-easy/

And you can refer to the Mechanize documentation here:

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html